# Проблема с файловой системой

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файловая-система, ext4

На виртуалке установлена убунту 10 с ext4. Во время проверки фс с помощью fsck виртуалку принудительно перезагрузили. После этого ОС не стартовала, во время загрузки стартует rescue grub. Загрузился с live cd. Увидел диск и его разделы sda1-основной, sda2-бутсектор? sda3-своп или свап (диск маленький 10 гигов). Подмонтировать основной не получилось, пишет "неизвестная файловая система".
Cделал ещё раз проверку fs с помощью fsck, выдало кучу фиксов, подмонтировал раздел а там то что на скриншоте
[image: sda1]

Вопрос, что это за файлы и директории # и как собрать фс в нормальный вид.
Вроде во время проверки fsck повреждённых суперблоков не было, да и я пробовал восстанавливаться из резервных суперблоков

Comment: IMHO, пора тушить свет, сушить вёсла и восстанавливаться с бэкапа

Comment: Тут такая ситуация, бэкапов то похоже что нет(;

Comment: Тогда просто тушить свет. Зато теперь вы (или владелец виртуалки) — админ, который уже делает резервные копии и корень как можно меньшего размера